# Why SDW file was not recognized in QGIS 1.8?

Tags: qgis, import, mac, mrsid, qgis-1

I'm running QGIS 1.8, and trying to load a SID file into my map. It imports fine, but seems to ignore the SDW file that comes with it, as the raster shows up without any apparent georeferencing. Is there a way to force the info in the SDW file to be applied to the SID?

Comment: Windows, Linux, Mac OS X ?

Comment: Mac OS X, if there is no way to force the use of the world file,...is there an easy way to extract and apply the info in the world file? Thank you.

Comment: If you are on Mac OS X, have you installed the [MrSid Plugin](http://www.kyngchaos.com/files/software/frameworks/GDAL-MrSID_Plugin-1.9.1-1.dmg) ?

Comment: I have installed the MrSID plugin, and the sid file loads with no problem, it just seems to ignore the sdw file that come along with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fell into the infamous "projection" trap. The raster layer was using a different projection from the rest of my project. All I needed to do was enable on-the-fly projection changes under the project settings.